# Generate an Angular 5 and Spring mvc CRUD application from an existing database

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, crud

How to generate an Angular 5 and Spring mvc using java 7 CRUD application from an existing database (oracle) ?

Comment: Really hard to tell what you want. Maybe use Hibernate's generate-DDL and then use Spring Data REST?

Comment: what do you mean by automatic? you have to write some code.

Comment: @VithuBati  I don't want to create CRUD manually, I want to generate the code like generate crud in symfony

Comment: @chrylis I found a solution to generate automatic crud with Jhipster but the problem that I need to create my application using Angular 5 and Java 7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You Can use Jhipster

JHipster is a development platform to generate, develop and deploy Spring Boot + Angular/React Web applications and Spring microservices

[Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/)

Comment: you're right but I need a solution to create my application using angular 5 and java 7

Comment: @LMA  Java 7 was removed with the 2.23 version. So there is no way to generate JHipster application with Java7 using the latest release.

There is a workaround  to use a previous JHipster version, <2.23

And note that java 7 has reach its end of life since April 2015 and it's strongly recommended to start a new project with Java 8

Comment: jhipster uses angular 6 and java 8 in its latest version and in the old version I have not found solutions with java 7 and angular 5

Comment: Are there other ways to generate crud like Jhipster?

Comment: With this build, https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/0acf65c Jhipster removed the Java 7 support. if you get the earlier version you can use Java 7 . You can try celario also. https://github.com/jaxio/celerio-angular-quickstart.